# YouTube Iframe API has 'Blocked a frame with origin' error only in Safari

Tags: iframe, youtube-api

I used iframe API like this

`<iframe id="youtubePlayer" type="text/html" width="100%" height="auto" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/someid?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://myurl.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Notice that I have changed `src` to `http` and added `origin`, but still I got the following error:

> Blockquote
>   Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://myurl.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

The problem only occurs in **Safari**. I did some debug and it seems like a `Sf()` only gets called in Safari in www-embed.js.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using https instead of http?

Comment: @noogui My site is using http and just for this to move my whole site to https is too much of a overhead. Also one thing I don't understand is that why iframe is trying to access my site(parent) and why that only happens in Safari.

Comment: Your error says you need to use https

Comment: @noogui Yes but I am looking for an answer why youtube iframe is trying to access my site.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a Safari implementation on iFrame has defect. On Safari, [YouTube iFrame API official page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) is giving the same error messages. So currently there is no way to circumvent this situation, until Safari fixes this.

Comment: Looks like Safari has fixed this issue.